# Combining Strings - Runs of Same character are kept together

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I am creating a code that combines two given strings together and obtains a string by alternating the characters from the two strings. 
For example: "xyz" and "abc" would get "xaybzc"

The problem I am having is that for any runs of the same character, those characters are supposed to be kept together.
For example: "abc" and "xyyz" would get "axbyycz"

This is what I have written:

```
public static java.lang.String interleaveWithRuns(java.lang.String s,    java.lang.String t)
{
    String str = "";
    int i = 0;
    while(i < s.length() && i < t.length())
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1))
        {
            str += s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i+1);
        }
        if(t.charAt(i) == t.charAt(i+1))
        {
            str += t.charAt(i) + t.charAt(i+1);
        }
        str += s.charAt(i) +""+ t.charAt(i); 
        i++;
    }
    while(i < s.length())
    {
        str += s.charAt(i); 
        i++;
    }
    while(i < t.length())
    {
        str += t.charAt(i); 
        i++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

I know that this portion is where the problem comes, but I am not sure what I should do instead to fix this.

```
 if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1))
 {
     str += s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i+1);
 }
 if(t.charAt(i) == t.charAt(i+1))
 {
     str += t.charAt(i) + t.charAt(i+1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may still run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if, when checking for `(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1))`, there actually **is no `s.charAt(i + 1)`** and you've hit the end of the string. Using recursion you can avoid this cleanly:

```
public static String concat(String a, String b)
{
    if(a.length() == 0){
        return b;
    }

    if(b.length() == 0){
        return a;
    }

    String a1 = "" + a.charAt(0);
    int i = 1;
    while(i < a.length() && a.charAt(i) == a.charAt(0))
    {
        a1 += a.charAt(i++);
    }

    String b1 = "" + b.charAt(0);
    i = 1;
    while(i < b.length() && b.charAt(i) == b.charAt(0))
    {
        b1 += b.charAt(i++);
    }

    return a1 + b1 + concat(a.substring(a1.length()), b.substring(b1.length()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular problem, you should track the iterators differently for the 2 strings. So this cannot be done by a single iterator variable `i`. You need `i` for string `s` and `j` for string `t`.

Also to avoid running into the array out of bound error especially when the same character is at the end of any of the string, there is a short circuit condition added to the if conditions for both the strings. like this : `(i < s.length() - 1) && further condition`

Below is the change to the `interleaveWithRuns` function.

```
public static java.lang.String interleaveWithRuns(java.lang.String s,
        java.lang.String t) {
    String str = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < s.length() && j < t.length()) {
        if ((i < s.length() - 1) && (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1))) {
            str += String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))
                    + String.valueOf(s.charAt(i + 1));
            str += String.valueOf(t.charAt(j));
            i++;
        } else if ((j < t.length() - 1) && (t.charAt(j) == t.charAt(j + 1))) {
            str += String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            str += String.valueOf(t.charAt(j))
                    + String.valueOf(t.charAt(j + 1));
            j++;
        } else {
            str += s.charAt(i) + "" + t.charAt(j);
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    while (i < s.length()) {
        str += s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    while (j < t.length()) {
        str += t.charAt(j);
        j++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

hope this helps.